# Paypal integration with Paypal IPN

Tags: kentico

Need some help for Paypal integration. I did all the configuration what is mentioned in the documentation like: Paypal gateway URL, Return URL (Success), and Notification url (~/CMSModules/Ecommerce/CMSPages/PayPalIPN.aspx). But my order status is not updating even after the successful payment.

- Using sandbox account for testing
- Able to redirect to Paypal page (Sandbox account) and on completion of payment, successfully redirected back to site (thank you page) configured as Return URL in settings
- Below is the sample return URL from after succesfult payment

/ConfirmPaypalPayment.aspx?amt=5.00&cc=USD&cm=en-US&item_name=Order%20ID%3A%201177&st=Completed&tx=83L5281177755044V

How can I make sure PaypalIPN is executed properly, 
what else I need to do/check other than what I mentioned above.
Can we debug the the code PaypalIPN.asps.cs
Is there any webpart I need to add on the thank you page(ConfirmPaypalPayment)

I am testing this in my local site with Sandbox account

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation says](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/e-commerce-features/configuring-your-store/configuring-payment-methods/configuring-paypal#ConfiguringPayPal-Custompaymentnotifications): The default Kentico PayPal provider does not utilize payment notifications – Webhooks or Instant Payment Notification (IPN). If you require payment notifications for any custom functionality or integrations, you need to configure the related options for your PayPal Business account and implement the required handlers (either within the Kentico web project or a custom project).

[The return page(thank you page)](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/configuring-kentico/managing-sites/configuring-settings-for-sites/settings-e-commerce/settings-paypal) must contain the **PayPal payment execution** web part, which processes the payment URL parameters provided by PayPal and completes transactions.

So there is no IPN in the default payment flow, if you want to use IPN take a look at [Creating a custom payment gateway](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/e-commerce-features/customizing-and-developing-your-store/payment-related-customizing/creating-a-custom-payment-gateway). There is there an explanation and a code sample.

Comment: Thanks Shof for the inputs. There is a option in Kentico to provide the Notify URL for Paypal along with return and cancel URL, I also enabled the IPN notification in Paypal account, but no luck. I didn't find any webpart named "PayPal payment execution" in my version. Is this available in latest version? I am using Kentico 10

Comment: I was talking about version 11, there is no Paypal payment execution in version 10.

Comment: I don't think enabling settings is enough, you have to have your paypal payment provider working. Notify URL and IPN notification are the same I believe. I haven't done integration for version 10,but  i've done this in earlier versions. I'll take a look at version 10.We  must have code samples coming with Kentico. I'll try to find them later.

Comment: Thanks Shof. Code is available in Kentico 10 (~/CMSModules/Ecommerce/CMSPages/PayPalIPN.aspx), also I am able to redirect to Paypal and do the payment (using Sandbox), but I am not sure what to do next, how this IPN is called and why order status is not updating. - Thanks again for your help.

Comment: IPN is  Instant page notification - "silent post" between paypal server and your server (so your server should be accessible to paypal, so paypal server can send transaction information to your server). On you silent post page (PayPalIPN.aspx) you have to process results recieved from Paypal using OrderInfo, setting status and recording other transaction information. By default PayPalIPN.cs already has the code sample to process the transaction information. You can check COM_Order table after you do your test transaction.

Comment: Thanks Shof, tried everything still not getting why my order status is not updating and how can i make sure Paypal is called (PayPalIPN.aspx) page? I did added some log , but looks like IPN page didn't called by Paypal.

Comment: You can wring something to Kentico event log:
https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/writing-to-the-kentico-event-log